# Selenium Test from Unix to Windows

Tags: java, selenium, unix, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

in my springboot application i have a Controller with endpoint startTest that call test Selenium package as jar.
Test.jar-->Class TestSuite --> method: LG0000001 use **WebDriver** class for simulate automation operation on browser (Chrome).

Both are packaged as JAR and deployed on Unix Server like Test.jar and BackEnd.jar.

I call service startTest from chrome on windows like:

> 10.233.233.235:8080/startTest/TestOther.jar/TestSuite/LG0000001

This is my Backend Class:

```
 @RestController
 public class Controller {

 @RequestMapping(value = {"/startTest/Test.jar/TestSuite/LG0000001"},method = RequestMethod.GET)  //this is for example i run only one method inside class
    public ResponseEntity<Esito> runTest(@PathVariable String jar, @PathVariable String class_name, @PathVariable Optional<String> test_name ) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, MalformedURLException, InstantiationException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        ReportInnerTests listener = new ReportInnerTests(); // is a overwrite for listener
        this.runOne(jar,class_name,test_name,listener);  //method for run test on Test.jar
        Map<String, String> summary= listener.getSummary();

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        Esito esito=new Esito();
        esito.setSummary(summary);
        return new ResponseEntity<Esito>(esito, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

public void runOne(String jar, String class_name, Optional<String> test_name, TestExecutionListener listener) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, MalformedURLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();

    ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
            new URL[] { new File(pathJars+"/"+jar).toURI().toURL() },
            getClass().getClassLoader()
        );

    loader.getClass();
    Class cls=Class.forName(class_name,true,loader);
    Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor();
    constructor.newInstance();

    LauncherDiscoveryRequest request;
    if (test_name.isPresent()) {
        Method m = cls.getMethod(test_name.get());
        request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(selectMethod(cls,m))
                .build();   
    }
    else{
        request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(selectClass(cls))
                .build();
    }

    TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(request);
    launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
    launcher.execute(request); //here I run  Test and work well with other Test that don't use Selenium

}
```

classTest for selenium is this that work if i run backend on my pc with windows:

```
@ExtendWith(TestReporter.class)
public class TestSuite {
  WebDriver driver;
  Actions action;
  JavascriptExecutor jse;
  public TestSuite() {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test_jar/chromedriver");  //here i load driver and work on Unix
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
     action = new Actions(driver);
     jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  }

  @Test
  public void LG0000001(){
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    LoginTest.login(driver, "http://xxxxxx.xxx.yyy.pages/dashboard",
            "axfas","str");   // this a test that use another my class that use "WebDriver"
  };
```

If i run other Test with Junit for example it work well and i view results. But when i run TestSelenium.jar i have this error:

```
    2020-04-09 16:10:40.548 ERROR 90384 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] with root cause
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

My question is if i can run TestSelenium on Unix called it by a RestPost call from windows:

```
10.233.233.235:8080/startTest/TestOther.jar/TestSuite/LG0000001
```

but i want view all automation operation on Browser on Chrome on windows where i call it.

Is possible or is all useless?? :-(
Thanks
Regards

Comment: Does the Linux machine have chrome installed?

Comment: no i must install on. but.I first want to understand if it is possible to do what I want to do..